# Updating blog resource by ID

Tags: c#, rest, api, put

I'm creating an API which would allow users to create, update and delete blog posts. I've got to the point where I want to now create an update handler for the blog post but creating a model for this call got me thinking..

For a PUT request should the `id` of the blog being updated be within the URI or be within the body like so:

In the URI:

```
/api/blog/23
```

In the body:

```
{
  "id": "23",
  "title": "new blog title"
}
```

Is there a right and wrong? If not, then what is generally the most followed convention for RESTful api's?

Answer (score 2):

Technically there is no right or wrong way to design an API. However, a well designed API will be much easier to understand.

**Assuming this is a [REST API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer), my preference is to stay consistent. If your API requires an ID within the URI to `GET` resources then keeping things consistent with an ID in the URI to `PUT` would be my recommendation.**

Microsoft has a good [API design guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/api-design#define-operations-in-terms-of-http-methods) article which also recommends to keep URIs consistent.

Answer (score 1):

[PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4), in HTTP, means something very specific

> The PUT method requests that the state of the target resource be created or replaced with the state defined by the representation enclosed in the request message payload.

It's a request that asks the server to change the servers copy to match the representation provided by the client.  Think "Save", or "Overwrite" -- a content management action.

So if the JSON representation of this blog post should be an id, a title, and nothing else -- then that would be fine.

If you intention is to *change* the title, while leaving the rest of the representation unchanged, then you either need to (a) send the entire representation, including your edit or (b) choose a method with different semantics (POST or PATCH could make sense).

The URI is an identifier -- think key in a hashtable/dictionary.  There's no particular reason that data encoded into the identifier needs to match data in the representation.  It certainly can -- we'll often encode into the URI information that the server will use in its own internal implementation -- but `/4ca7fce6-efce-42d1-8fc6-666c3cae4f90` is a perfectly valid identifier for a resource.